# How to store info for multiple users

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js

I am working on a DnD discord bot for friends, I want to be able to have the players use a command and enter in their info (ex. first/last name of the character, race, class, etc.)

I tried using maps but im new to using maps and couldn't figure out how to nest others and/or how to access it.

How would I accomplish something like this?

I've looked into using arrays or lists but dont know where to start

So im thinking maybe something like this v using the users id as the key so if the either mentioned user or author uses a certain command it will check if one is already made and if it is do something else and if not generate something like this they can fill out with the information

also I know map() can nest like this, its just I dont really know how to access the information stored below the key like I want someone to use a command like !set character firstname and be able to put their characters first name.

everytime i try to do that though I always get an error saying something along the lines of key.firstname.get() is not a function

```
{ 
 key: member.id { 
   firstname: 'Bob', 
   lastname: 'Doofensmurf', 
   race: 'human', 
   class: 'Rogue'
   // Etc.
 },
 key: another.member.id { 
   firstname: 'Jack', 
   lastname: 'Nickleson', 
   race: 'Elf', 
   class: 'Wizard'
   // Etc.
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax is wrong. It should be like this:

```
let arrayname = [
    {
        key: member.id,
        firstname: 'Jack',
        lastname: 'Nickelsen',
        race: 'elf'
        // etc
    },
    {
        key: anothermember.id,
        firstname: 'Jack',
        lastname: 'beanstalk',
        race: 'elf'
        // etc
    }
];
```

Note that I changed the opening and closing brackets to [ and ] because it is now an array, not an object. And to access,

```
alert(arrayname[0].firstname);
```

It should show Jack.

Comment: Ok awesome I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Actually I am wanting to be able to access specific users character info with this would I be able to do that?

Comment: You have to be more specific with your question. I can only guess what you really want to do. But it is possible to obtain any info using this. For example: `let characters = [{ name: "mike", race: "elf" }, { name: "legolas", race: "elf" }, { name: "john", race: "human" }, { name: "paulo", race: "human" }]; alert(characters.filter(char => char.race == "human"));` the alert will give you all the humans in the list. I suggest you read tutorials on Javascript objects and arrays. There are thousands of tutorials on the internet.